# Atualização da data em um app no React

Tags: react, data, react-native, react-hooks

Olá, estou fazendo um app de notas e gostaria de, quando eu atualizo minha nota no modal, que a data também altere - e seja a mais recente. Consigo ver no console.log certinho a data atualizada, mas só aparece na tela quando eu clico duas vezes seguidas. Alguém sabe como eu poderia resolver isso? Obrigada!

Componente App.jsx

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';
import './App.css';
import moment from 'moment';
import AddTask from './components/AddTask';
import Tasks from './components/Tasks';

const App = () => {
  const [tasks, setTasks] = useState([]);

  const handleTaskClick = (taskId) => {
    const newTasks = tasks.map((task) => {
      task.id = taskId;
    });
    setTasks(newTasks);
  };

  const handleTaskAdd = (taskText, taskTitle) => {
    const date = `(${moment().format('MMM Mo HH:mm A')})`;
    const newTasks = [
      ...tasks,
      {
        text: taskText,
        title: taskTitle,
        id: uuidv4(), //set an random id number from npm library
        date: date,
        updateTask: { updateTask },
      },
    ];
    setTasks(newTasks);
  };

  const handleTaskRemove = (taskId) => {
    const newTasks = tasks.filter((task) => task.id !== taskId);
    setTasks(newTasks);
  };

  const updateTask = (taskId, newTitle, newText, newDate) => {
    const updatedTask = tasks.map((task) => {
      if (task.id === taskId) {
        return { ...task, text: newTitle, title: newText, date: newDate };
      }
      return task;
    });

    setTasks(updatedTask);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div className="container">
        <h1>NOTES</h1>
        <AddTask handleTaskAdd={handleTaskAdd} />
        <Tasks
          tasks={tasks}
          handleTaskClick={handleTaskClick}
          handleTaskRemove={handleTaskRemove}
          updateTask={updateTask}
        />
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Componente Task.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import './Task.css';

import AddModal from './AddModal';

const Task = ({ task, handleTaskRemove, updateTask }) => {
  return (
    <div className="task-container">
      <div className="task-container-text">
        <div className="task-title">
          {task.text} {task.date}
        </div>
        <div className="task-title">{task.title}</div>
      </div>

      <div className="button-container">
        <AddModal
          title={task.text}
          text={task.title}
          id={task.id}
          updateTask={updateTask}
          date={task.date}
        />
        <button
          className="remove-task-button"
          onClick={() => {
            if (window.confirm('Are you sure you want to delete your note?')) {
              handleTaskRemove(task.id);
            }
          }}
        >
          X
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Task;
```

Componente AddModal.jsx

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';
import Modal from 'react-bootstrap/Modal';
import moment from 'moment';

function AddModal({ title, text, date, id, updateTask }) {
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);

  const handleClose = () => setShow(false);
  const handleShow = () => setShow(true);

  const [taskBody, setTaskBody] = useState(text);
  const [taskTitle, setTaskTitle] = useState(title);
  const [taskDate, setTaskDate] = useState(date);

  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <button onClick={handleShow} className="edit-task-button">
          Edit
        </button>
      </div>

      <Modal
        show={show}
        onHide={handleClose}
        backdrop="static"
        keyboard={false}
      >
        <Modal.Header closeButton>
          <Modal.Title>Do you want to change something?</Modal.Title>
        </Modal.Header>
        <Modal.Body>
          <div className="add-task-container">
            <form className="add-task-input-container">
              <input
                onChange={(e) => {
                  setTaskTitle(e.target.value);
                }}
                value={taskTitle}
                id="title"
                type="text"
                placeholder="Title"
                className="add-task-title"
              ></input>
              <textarea
                required
                onChange={(e) => {
                  setTaskBody(e.target.value);
                }}
                value={taskBody}
                name="textarea"
                id="textarea"
                className="add-task-input"
                type="text"
                placeholder="Your notes..."
              ></textarea>
            </form>
          </div>
        </Modal.Body>
        <Modal.Footer>
          <Button variant="secondary" onClick={handleClose}>
            Close
          </Button>
          <Button
            variant="primary"
            onClick={(e) => {
              handleClose();
              e.preventDefault();
              setTaskDate(`(${moment().format('MMM Mo HH:mm A')})`);
              updateTask(id, taskTitle, taskBody, taskDate);
            }}
          >
            Update
          </Button>
        </Modal.Footer>
      </Modal>
    </>
  );
}

export default AddModal;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

você tem que utilizar o useEffect do react, o funcionamento dele basicamente é carregar todos os dados que estão dentro dele (normalmente se coloca a api nele) antes de carregar a página e ele também recarrega a página caso existir alguma alteração da variavel que você setar para ficar verificando ela.
[Verifique essa parte da biblioteca](https://pt-br.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#conditionally-firing-an-effect)
Então seria o seguinte:

```
    useEffect(()=>{
          ...sua lógica aqui
    },[nota])
```

Então todas as vezes que houver alteração na variavel nota, esse useEffect será executado

Comment: Eu imaginei que teria que usar o useEffect, mas como não sabia usar direito - e eu achei que era mais para API mesmo - não tentei. Eu uso no AddModal mesmo?

Comment: Consegui Eduardo! Mesmo não sabendo muito bem fui fuçando e ai finalmente deu certo! Obrigada :)